# Anime about black haired teen who opens a manga shop in another world

Tags: outbreak-company

What I remember is that a young black-haired teen gets transported to another world but he notices that there is no manga in that world, so he stayed there and opened a manga shop or library. He also is tended by a young, blonde and kind maid whom he also taught to write or something.

The ruler of that world is interested in the main character. The ruler is a very young stubborn and spoiled girl, who gets her way, and who likes manga.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7):

You're probably thinking of [*Outbreak Company*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outbreak_Company)

> Shin'ichi Kanō is a young secluded otaku who is offered a job thanks to his vast knowledge of anime, manga and video games. However, just after meeting his new employer, he is kidnapped, awakening in an alternate world with a fantasy setup. Shin'ichi is then informed that he was in fact selected by the Japanese government to help improve his country's relations with this new world by establishing a company to spread the unique products of the Japanese culture to this new, unexplored market.

[image: Play ball!]